# could not deserialize - hibernate spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to expose data as a rest webservices, but when I run it appears:
[image: could not deserialize]

**The output is:**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$1.doExtract(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1696) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1628) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1515) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:726) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:323) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I am using spring boot and spring data rest and connect to a Oracle Data Base

And use NetBeans IDE 8.1, JDK 1.8 and Tomcat 8.0.27.0

**This is my aplication.properties**

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#Oracle connection
oracle.username=pass
oracle.password=pass
oracle.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@182.10.53.43:1521:QABD1
```

**My Entity classs**

```
package ec.edu.utpl.gestiondatos.tesis.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Efren
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "TDI_DOCENTE")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TdiDocente.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TdiDocente t")})
public class TdiDocente implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8846422129143878578L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DO_ID")
    private BigDecimal doId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 13)
    @Column(name = "DO_IDENTIFICACION")
    private String doIdentificacion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "DO_APELLIDO_PATERNO")
    private String doApellidoPaterno;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "DO_APELLIDO_MATERNO")
    private String doApellidoMaterno;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "DO_PRIMER_NOMBRE")
    private String doPrimerNombre;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "DO_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE")
    private String doSegundoNombre;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_NACIMIENTO")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaNacimiento;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_NSGA")
    private BigInteger doEquIdNsga;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_SGA")
    private BigInteger doEquIdSga;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_SICA")
    private BigInteger doEquIdSica;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_EVA")
    private BigInteger doEquIdEva;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "DO_GENERO")
    private String doGenero;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_CREACION")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaCreacion;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_ACTUALIZACION")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaActualizacion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 1)
    @Column(name = "DO_ACTIVO")
    private String doActivo;
    @Size(max = 120)
    @Column(name = "DO_CORREO_PRI")
    private String doCorreoPri;
    @Size(max = 120)
    @Column(name = "DO_CORREO_SEC")
    private String doCorreoSec;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "DO_TELEFONO_DOM")
    private String doTelefonoDom;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "DO_CELULAR_PRI")
    private String doCelularPri;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "DO_CELULAR_SEC")
    private String doCelularSec;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 1)
    @Column(name = "DO_PROMETEO")
    private String doPrometeo;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_CITTES")
    private BigInteger doEquIdCittes;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_NSGA2")
    private BigInteger doEquIdNsga2;
    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "DO_IDENTIFICACION_RRHH")
    private String doIdentificacionRrhh;
    @Size(max = 1)
    @Column(name = "DO_VALIDADO_RRHH")
    private String doValidadoRrhh;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "DO_EXTENSION")
    private String doExtension;
    @Column(name = "DO_TECNICO_DOCENTE")
    private Character doTecnicoDocente;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_INGRESO")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaIngreso;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_SALIDA")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaSalida;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "USUARIO_APEX_CREA")
    private String usuarioApexCrea;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "USUARIO_APEX_ACTUALIZA")
    private String usuarioApexActualiza;
    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "DO_CORREO_PERSONAL")
    private String doCorreoPersonal;
    @Size(max = 1)
    @Column(name = "DO_ES_ADMINISTRATIVO")
    private String doEsAdministrativo;
    @Column(name = "DO_ID_TIPO_SANGRE")
    private BigInteger doIdTipoSangre;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_RR_HH")
    private BigInteger doEquIdRrHh;
    @Size(max = 25)
    @Column(name = "DO_IDENTIFICACION_NOMINA")
    private String doIdentificacionNomina;
    @Size(max = 1)
    @Column(name = "DO_REPETIDO_NSGA")
    private String doRepetidoNsga;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "DO_OBSERVACIONES_REPETIDO")
    private String doObservacionesRepetido;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQUI_ID_NOMINA")
    private BigInteger doEquiIdNomina;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQUI_ID_REGISTRO")
    private BigInteger doEquiIdRegistro;
    @Column(name = "DO_CANTON_NACIMIENTO")
    private BigInteger doCantonNacimiento;
    @Column(name = "DO_PROVINCIA_NACIMIENTO")
    private BigInteger doProvinciaNacimiento;
    @Column(name = "DO_TIPO_DISCAPACIDAD")
    private BigInteger doTipoDiscapacidad;
    @Column(name = "DO_PORCENTAJE_DISCAPACIDAD")
    private BigInteger doPorcentajeDiscapacidad;
    @Size(max = 25)
    @Column(name = "DO_NUMERO_CARNET_CONADIS")
    private String doNumeroCarnetConadis;
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "DO_OBSERVACION")
    private String doObservacion;
    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "DO_IDENTIFICACION_NSGA")
    private String doIdentificacionNsga;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "DO_FOTO")
    private Serializable doFoto;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "DO_FOTO_MIMETYPE")
    private String doFotoMimetype;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "DO_FOTO_FILENAME")
    private String doFotoFilename;
    @Column(name = "DO_FOTO_LAST_UPDATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFotoLastUpdate;
    @Column(name = "DO_EQU_ID_NSGA3")
    private BigInteger doEquIdNsga3;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_INICIO_ADENDA")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaInicioAdenda;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_FIN_ADENDA")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaFinAdenda;
    @Column(name = "DO_FECHA_VALIDACION_RRHH")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date doFechaValidacionRrhh;

    public TdiDocente() {
    }

    public TdiDocente(BigDecimal doId) {
        this.doId = doId;
    }

    public TdiDocente(BigDecimal doId, String doIdentificacion, String doApellidoPaterno, String doPrimerNombre, String doGenero, Date doFechaCreacion, String doActivo, String doPrometeo) {
        this.doId = doId;
        this.doIdentificacion = doIdentificacion;
        this.doApellidoPaterno = doApellidoPaterno;
        this.doPrimerNombre = doPrimerNombre;
        this.doGenero = doGenero;
        this.doFechaCreacion = doFechaCreacion;
        this.doActivo = doActivo;
        this.doPrometeo = doPrometeo;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDoId() {
        return doId;
    }

    public void setDoId(BigDecimal doId) {
        this.doId = doId;
    }

    public String getDoIdentificacion() {
        return doIdentificacion;
    }

    public void setDoIdentificacion(String doIdentificacion) {
        this.doIdentificacion = doIdentificacion;
    }

    public String getDoApellidoPaterno() {
        return doApellidoPaterno;
    }

    public void setDoApellidoPaterno(String doApellidoPaterno) {
        this.doApellidoPaterno = doApellidoPaterno;
    }

    public String getDoApellidoMaterno() {
        return doApellidoMaterno;
    }

    public void setDoApellidoMaterno(String doApellidoMaterno) {
        this.doApellidoMaterno = doApellidoMaterno;
    }

    public String getDoPrimerNombre() {
        return doPrimerNombre;
    }

    public void setDoPrimerNombre(String doPrimerNombre) {
        this.doPrimerNombre = doPrimerNombre;
    }

    public String getDoSegundoNombre() {
        return doSegundoNombre;
    }

    public void setDoSegundoNombre(String doSegundoNombre) {
        this.doSegundoNombre = doSegundoNombre;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaNacimiento() {
        return doFechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setDoFechaNacimiento(Date doFechaNacimiento) {
        this.doFechaNacimiento = doFechaNacimiento;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdNsga() {
        return doEquIdNsga;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdNsga(BigInteger doEquIdNsga) {
        this.doEquIdNsga = doEquIdNsga;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdSga() {
        return doEquIdSga;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdSga(BigInteger doEquIdSga) {
        this.doEquIdSga = doEquIdSga;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdSica() {
        return doEquIdSica;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdSica(BigInteger doEquIdSica) {
        this.doEquIdSica = doEquIdSica;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdEva() {
        return doEquIdEva;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdEva(BigInteger doEquIdEva) {
        this.doEquIdEva = doEquIdEva;
    }

    public String getDoGenero() {
        return doGenero;
    }

    public void setDoGenero(String doGenero) {
        this.doGenero = doGenero;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaCreacion() {
        return doFechaCreacion;
    }

    public void setDoFechaCreacion(Date doFechaCreacion) {
        this.doFechaCreacion = doFechaCreacion;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaActualizacion() {
        return doFechaActualizacion;
    }

    public void setDoFechaActualizacion(Date doFechaActualizacion) {
        this.doFechaActualizacion = doFechaActualizacion;
    }

    public String getDoActivo() {
        return doActivo;
    }

    public void setDoActivo(String doActivo) {
        this.doActivo = doActivo;
    }

    public String getDoCorreoPri() {
        return doCorreoPri;
    }

    public void setDoCorreoPri(String doCorreoPri) {
        this.doCorreoPri = doCorreoPri;
    }

    public String getDoCorreoSec() {
        return doCorreoSec;
    }

    public void setDoCorreoSec(String doCorreoSec) {
        this.doCorreoSec = doCorreoSec;
    }

    public String getDoTelefonoDom() {
        return doTelefonoDom;
    }

    public void setDoTelefonoDom(String doTelefonoDom) {
        this.doTelefonoDom = doTelefonoDom;
    }

    public String getDoCelularPri() {
        return doCelularPri;
    }

    public void setDoCelularPri(String doCelularPri) {
        this.doCelularPri = doCelularPri;
    }

    public String getDoCelularSec() {
        return doCelularSec;
    }

    public void setDoCelularSec(String doCelularSec) {
        this.doCelularSec = doCelularSec;
    }

    public String getDoPrometeo() {
        return doPrometeo;
    }

    public void setDoPrometeo(String doPrometeo) {
        this.doPrometeo = doPrometeo;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdCittes() {
        return doEquIdCittes;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdCittes(BigInteger doEquIdCittes) {
        this.doEquIdCittes = doEquIdCittes;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdNsga2() {
        return doEquIdNsga2;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdNsga2(BigInteger doEquIdNsga2) {
        this.doEquIdNsga2 = doEquIdNsga2;
    }

    public String getDoIdentificacionRrhh() {
        return doIdentificacionRrhh;
    }

    public void setDoIdentificacionRrhh(String doIdentificacionRrhh) {
        this.doIdentificacionRrhh = doIdentificacionRrhh;
    }

    public String getDoValidadoRrhh() {
        return doValidadoRrhh;
    }

    public void setDoValidadoRrhh(String doValidadoRrhh) {
        this.doValidadoRrhh = doValidadoRrhh;
    }

    public String getDoExtension() {
        return doExtension;
    }

    public void setDoExtension(String doExtension) {
        this.doExtension = doExtension;
    }

    public Character getDoTecnicoDocente() {
        return doTecnicoDocente;
    }

    public void setDoTecnicoDocente(Character doTecnicoDocente) {
        this.doTecnicoDocente = doTecnicoDocente;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaIngreso() {
        return doFechaIngreso;
    }

    public void setDoFechaIngreso(Date doFechaIngreso) {
        this.doFechaIngreso = doFechaIngreso;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaSalida() {
        return doFechaSalida;
    }

    public void setDoFechaSalida(Date doFechaSalida) {
        this.doFechaSalida = doFechaSalida;
    }

    public String getUsuarioApexCrea() {
        return usuarioApexCrea;
    }

    public void setUsuarioApexCrea(String usuarioApexCrea) {
        this.usuarioApexCrea = usuarioApexCrea;
    }

    public String getUsuarioApexActualiza() {
        return usuarioApexActualiza;
    }

    public void setUsuarioApexActualiza(String usuarioApexActualiza) {
        this.usuarioApexActualiza = usuarioApexActualiza;
    }

    public String getDoCorreoPersonal() {
        return doCorreoPersonal;
    }

    public void setDoCorreoPersonal(String doCorreoPersonal) {
        this.doCorreoPersonal = doCorreoPersonal;
    }

    public String getDoEsAdministrativo() {
        return doEsAdministrativo;
    }

    public void setDoEsAdministrativo(String doEsAdministrativo) {
        this.doEsAdministrativo = doEsAdministrativo;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoIdTipoSangre() {
        return doIdTipoSangre;
    }

    public void setDoIdTipoSangre(BigInteger doIdTipoSangre) {
        this.doIdTipoSangre = doIdTipoSangre;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdRrHh() {
        return doEquIdRrHh;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdRrHh(BigInteger doEquIdRrHh) {
        this.doEquIdRrHh = doEquIdRrHh;
    }

    public String getDoIdentificacionNomina() {
        return doIdentificacionNomina;
    }

    public void setDoIdentificacionNomina(String doIdentificacionNomina) {
        this.doIdentificacionNomina = doIdentificacionNomina;
    }

    public String getDoRepetidoNsga() {
        return doRepetidoNsga;
    }

    public void setDoRepetidoNsga(String doRepetidoNsga) {
        this.doRepetidoNsga = doRepetidoNsga;
    }

    public String getDoObservacionesRepetido() {
        return doObservacionesRepetido;
    }

    public void setDoObservacionesRepetido(String doObservacionesRepetido) {
        this.doObservacionesRepetido = doObservacionesRepetido;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquiIdNomina() {
        return doEquiIdNomina;
    }

    public void setDoEquiIdNomina(BigInteger doEquiIdNomina) {
        this.doEquiIdNomina = doEquiIdNomina;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquiIdRegistro() {
        return doEquiIdRegistro;
    }

    public void setDoEquiIdRegistro(BigInteger doEquiIdRegistro) {
        this.doEquiIdRegistro = doEquiIdRegistro;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoCantonNacimiento() {
        return doCantonNacimiento;
    }

    public void setDoCantonNacimiento(BigInteger doCantonNacimiento) {
        this.doCantonNacimiento = doCantonNacimiento;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoProvinciaNacimiento() {
        return doProvinciaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setDoProvinciaNacimiento(BigInteger doProvinciaNacimiento) {
        this.doProvinciaNacimiento = doProvinciaNacimiento;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoTipoDiscapacidad() {
        return doTipoDiscapacidad;
    }

    public void setDoTipoDiscapacidad(BigInteger doTipoDiscapacidad) {
        this.doTipoDiscapacidad = doTipoDiscapacidad;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoPorcentajeDiscapacidad() {
        return doPorcentajeDiscapacidad;
    }

    public void setDoPorcentajeDiscapacidad(BigInteger doPorcentajeDiscapacidad) {
        this.doPorcentajeDiscapacidad = doPorcentajeDiscapacidad;
    }

    public String getDoNumeroCarnetConadis() {
        return doNumeroCarnetConadis;
    }

    public void setDoNumeroCarnetConadis(String doNumeroCarnetConadis) {
        this.doNumeroCarnetConadis = doNumeroCarnetConadis;
    }

    public String getDoObservacion() {
        return doObservacion;
    }

    public void setDoObservacion(String doObservacion) {
        this.doObservacion = doObservacion;
    }

    public String getDoIdentificacionNsga() {
        return doIdentificacionNsga;
    }

    public void setDoIdentificacionNsga(String doIdentificacionNsga) {
        this.doIdentificacionNsga = doIdentificacionNsga;
    }

    public Serializable getDoFoto() {
        return doFoto;
    }

    public void setDoFoto(Serializable doFoto) {
        this.doFoto = doFoto;
    }

    public String getDoFotoMimetype() {
        return doFotoMimetype;
    }

    public void setDoFotoMimetype(String doFotoMimetype) {
        this.doFotoMimetype = doFotoMimetype;
    }

    public String getDoFotoFilename() {
        return doFotoFilename;
    }

    public void setDoFotoFilename(String doFotoFilename) {
        this.doFotoFilename = doFotoFilename;
    }

    public Date getDoFotoLastUpdate() {
        return doFotoLastUpdate;
    }

    public void setDoFotoLastUpdate(Date doFotoLastUpdate) {
        this.doFotoLastUpdate = doFotoLastUpdate;
    }

    public BigInteger getDoEquIdNsga3() {
        return doEquIdNsga3;
    }

    public void setDoEquIdNsga3(BigInteger doEquIdNsga3) {
        this.doEquIdNsga3 = doEquIdNsga3;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaInicioAdenda() {
        return doFechaInicioAdenda;
    }

    public void setDoFechaInicioAdenda(Date doFechaInicioAdenda) {
        this.doFechaInicioAdenda = doFechaInicioAdenda;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaFinAdenda() {
        return doFechaFinAdenda;
    }

    public void setDoFechaFinAdenda(Date doFechaFinAdenda) {
        this.doFechaFinAdenda = doFechaFinAdenda;
    }

    public Date getDoFechaValidacionRrhh() {
        return doFechaValidacionRrhh;
    }

    public void setDoFechaValidacionRrhh(Date doFechaValidacionRrhh) {
        this.doFechaValidacionRrhh = doFechaValidacionRrhh;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (doId != null ? doId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof TdiDocente)) {
            return false;
        }
        TdiDocente other = (TdiDocente) object;
        if ((this.doId == null && other.doId != null) || (this.doId != null && !this.doId.equals(other.doId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ec.edu.utpl.gestiondatos.tesis.entities.TdiDocente[ doId=" + doId + " ]";
    }

}
```

**And this is my Repository**

```
package ec.edu.utpl.gestiondatos.tesis.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import ec.edu.utpl.gestiondatos.tesis.entities.TdiDocente;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface TdiDocenteRepository extends CrudRepository<TdiDocente, Long> {

    List<TdiDocente> findBydoIdentificacion(@Param("doIdentificacion") String doIdentificacion);
}
```

Comment: Efren, please provide your stacktrace to see exactly what error and from where is comes.

Comment: @TurbutAlin sorry, I updated my post

Comment: I think your stacktrace should have other errors in there. This one does not show the reason for the actual error. Please leave all your stacktrace which should also contain from where the call starts.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try annotating your controller with

> @Transactional

the problem could be - Jackson is trying to serialize a lazy loaded field and the hibernate session is not available then

Comment: But  I don´t have any controller, I just have my entity and my repository, where i can put the @Transactional.

Comment: your web service? the Rest endpoint you access to view that error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a recent OJDBC jar for the Oracle thin client. I had a similar issue and upgrading to OJBC 6 resolved it.